# Laravel seeding - Array to string conversion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

I am having this seeder

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Foo;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class FooSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        foreach (['Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4'] as $foo) {
            Foo::factory()->create([
                'fooName' => $foo,
                'fooUsername' => Str::slug($foo),
                'parent_id' => 1, // <-- line 17 where is failing on stacktrace
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code of my factory

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class FooFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition()
    {
        $foo = $this->faker->word();

        return [
            'fooName' => $foo,
            'fooUsername' => Str::slug($foo),
            'parent_id' => rand(1, 5),
        ];
    }

    public function noParent()
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'parent_id' => null,
            ];
        });
    }
}
```

However when I try to run this seeder I get the following error

```
ErrorException 

  Array to string conversion

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php:835
    831▕ 
    832▕         $result = array_shift($segments);
    833▕ 
    834▕         foreach ($segments as $segment) {
  ➜ 835▕             $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;
    836▕         }
    837▕ 
    838▕         return $result;
    839▕     }

      +18 vendor frames 
  19  database/seeders/FooSeeder.php:17
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory::create(["Value 1", "value-1"])
```

I am getting very confused because if I `dd($foo)` inside the foreach loop the value I get is a string type. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: strange... please post a code of `Foo` model, maybe problem is there

Comment: Your error is pointing at an issue with `Factory::create(["Value 1", "value-1"])`, which isn't in your code, and shouldn't be the result of the code you posted. Your code `Foo::factory()->create(['fooName' => 'Value 1', 'fooUsername' => 'value-1', 'parent_id' => 1])` (or similar) should be fine. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75734998/edit) to include your `Foo.php` Model; there might be something in there messing with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because [`range()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) returns an `array` containing a sequence of the given numbers (in your case from 0 to 4 inclusive).

If you want each `parent_id` to have any value somewhere between 0 and 4 (inclusive), then you should use something like [`rand(0, 4)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Not sure if this was the issue. I have changed this instead of `rand(0,5)` to a hardcoded value like 1 and still getting the same error

Comment: I have added the code of the factory as well

Comment: @ltdev I cannot reproduce the error you get. The seed succeeds for me. Please make sure to save your code and clear the cache.